# jQuery.parseJSON \u0092 character is not parsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a text encoded from php with an ajax function with de php utf8_encode.If I print it in the console directly the text is displayed as follows :

```
"projects":[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "CURSOS DE PERIODISME",
        "description": "Els cursos tenen l\u0092objectiu d\u0092aprofundir en l\u0092actitud period\u00edstica dels alumnes."
    }
]
```

When I use the jquery.parseJSON and print the text again into the description, the text is parsed as follows:

Els cursos tenen lobjectiu daprofundir en lactitud periodística dels alumnes.

All other unicode characters are well parsed, but why \u0092 is not parsed? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your original string? Tried removing utf8_encode?

Comment: Just a remark: FF14 `JSON.parse` parses your string correctly including `\u0092`.

Comment: If I romve the uf8_encode returns null with the json_encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[U+0092](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0092) is a control character, perhaps it's being parsed but you're not seeing it because of how you're using the string.

For example, this code which does no JSON parsing at all:

```
(function() {

  var strWith = "Els cursos tenen l\u0092objectiu d\u0092aprofundir";
  var strWithout = "Els cursos tenen lobjectiu daprofundir";

  display("With    (" + strWith.length + "): " + strWith);
  display("Without (" + strWithout.length + "): " + strWithout);

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('pre');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/igocof) | [source](http://jsbin.com/igocof/edit)

Output:

```
With    (40): Els cursos tenen lobjectiu daprofundir
Without (38): Els cursos tenen lobjectiu daprofundir
```

As you can see, they look the same with and without the control character, but we can see from the lengths that the control character *is* included in the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and what can I do to display it? I would like to see : 
Els cursos tenen l'objectiu d'aprofundir

Comment: @SergiMínguez: `str = str.replace(/\u0092/g, "'")` should do it: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/igocof/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/igocof/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

It is parsed by jQuery. A simple test can show you:

```
> $.parseJSON('"\\u0092"').length 
1
> $.parseJSON('"\\u0092"').charCodeAt(0)
146
> $.parseJSON('"\\u0092"').charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
"92"
```

It only won't get displayed, see @TJCrowders answer for that.