# Escaping JSON apostrophe before PHP's json_encode truncates?

Tags: php, getjson, json

I have a field in a MySQL database (utf8_general_ci) that contains a curly (smart?) apostrophe: `Owner’s...`

This prints fine with no special handling if I access the PHP page that pulls it from the DB. However, I am trying to access it via a $.getJSON request on another page, so I used PHP's json_encode. It truncates the value so that it reads `Owner`, then successfully encodes the rest of the data. If I use PHP's utf8_encode on the field before I json_encode, it includes the full value with the `’` encoded to `\u0092` which then doesn't print anything on the page, giving me `Owners`. PHP's `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` have no effect.

Looking at the request in Chrome's tools, `Owner’s` is shown as `Owner�s` on the $.getJSON page.

Can anyone help me out here? I have read other questions on SO and the web but I cannot find anything that helps and I haven't worked much with JSON.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `If I use PHP's utf8_encode on the field before I json_encode, it includes the full value with the ’ encoded to \u0092` that sounds like the way to go, that looks right. Can you elaborate on how that fails exactly? What does this scenario look like in Chrome's tools?

Comment: I think you need to set the encoding for the page you are outputting too. Also, you might need to decode the UTF-8.

Comment: @Pekka: On the page, `Owner\0092s` is rendered as `Owners`, in Chrome's Tools, it looks like `Owner\0092s`. @crush, I am concerned this is not converting correctly because a search for \0092 indicates it is a control character (?) not an apostrophe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030851/jquery-parsejson-u0092-character-is-not-parsed

Comment: Check out [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170) you may have a connection problem (ISO-8859-1 charset)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using PHP's `utf8_encode()` before my `json_encode()` did indeed stop the data from cutting off after the `’` but it also encoded it to `\0092` which did not display (control character). When I used MySQL's `SET NAMES utf8` before my query, I did not have to use `utf8_encode()` at all, and my json was encoded correctly with `’` mapping to `\u2019`, which displays nicely.

Thanks for the link @Pekka, it helped me narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 11):

For details: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Example:

```
echo json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: @delive You may try with the necessary options `JSON_HEX_QUOT, JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_AMP, JSON_HEX_APOS, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR ` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.