# Escaping an apostrophe dynamically when converting a PHP array to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, utf-8

I am using an Advanced Custom Fields repeater to dynamically create a list of locations to be placed on a Google map. I am trying to convert my PHP array to JSON so that I can access the locations in my Google Maps script file. The issue I am running into is that locations with an apostrophe are causing an error in the Javascript. I know that the apostrophes need to be escaped, but I am not sure how to do it dynamically.

Here is my PHP:

```
$locations = get_field('locations');
$jsonLocations = json_encode($locations);
```

Then I am trying to pass the PHP array to Javascript like so:

```
var jsonLocations = '<?php echo $jsonLocations; ?>';
```

This is what's causing me the problem. I tried using `utf8_encode` based on [another question I found on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097518/escaping-json-apostrophe-before-phps-json-encode-truncates), but that gave me a `null` result.

```
$locations = get_field('locations');
$jsonLocations = utf8_encode($locations);
$jsonLocations = json_encode($jsonLocations);
```

Comment: JSON_HEX_QUOT, JSON_HEX_APOS http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @bassxzero thank you, that worked! Please add as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON_HEX_QUOT`, `JSON_HEX_APOS`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php